# ConvertFrom-String template issues with an irregular data set

Tags: powershell, machine-learning, powershell-5.0

I have a data set that I'm trying to normalize into a `PsCustomObject`. I've been trying to use the machine learning template feature of `ConvertFrom-String` with partial success. One problem is that all the examples I can find have datasets with the same structure. Mine are not all the same.

I'm sure a wiz could do it straight from the raw data, but I've manipulated it somewhat to get to where I am.

### Raw sample data:

```
IDE00001-ENG99061-Production mode-Access control
IDE00001-ENG115730-Production mode-Aussenbeleuchtung
IDE00001-ENG112304-Production mode-Heckwischer
IDE00001-ENG98647-Production mode-Interior lighting
IDE00001-ENG115729-Production mode-Scheinwerferreinigung
IDE00001-ENG115731-Production mode-Virtuel_pedal
IDE00002-Transport mode
IDE00820-Activating and deactivating all development messages
IDE01550-Service position
IDE02152-Characteristics in production mode
IDE02269-MAS04382-Acknowledgement signals-Optical feedback during locking
IDE02332-Deactivate production mode
IDE02488-DWA Interior monitoring
IDE02711-ENG116690-Rear Window Wiper-Automatisches Heckwischen
```

Using the following script:

```
$lines = $testText.Split("`n") #$testText is the above data wrapped in a here-string
$NewLines = @()
foreach($line in $lines)
{
    [regex]$regex = '-'
    $HyphenCount = $regex.Matches($line).count
    #$HyphenCount
    switch ($HyphenCount)
    {
        1{
            $newLines += $line -replace "-",","
         }
        2{
            $split = $line.Split("-",2)
            $newlines += $split -join ","
         }
        3{
            if($line.Contains("mode-"))
            {
                #$line
                $split = $line.Split("-",4)
                $newlines += $split -join ","
            }
            else
            {
                $split = $line.Split("-",3)
                $newlines += $split -join ","
            }
         }        
        4{
           $split = $line.Split("-",3) #this assumes the fourth hyphen is part of description
           $newlines += $split -join ","
         }
        5{
           $split = $line.Split("-",4) 
           $newlines += $split -join ","
         }
    }
}
```

### Manipulated data set:

I've got the raw data looking like:

```
IDE00001,ENG99061,Production mode,Access control
IDE00001,ENG115730,Production mode,Aussenbeleuchtung
IDE00001,ENG112304,Production mode,Heckwischer
IDE00001,ENG98647,Production mode,Interior lighting
IDE00001,ENG115729,Production mode,Scheinwerferreinigung
IDE00001,ENG115731,Production mode,Virtuel_pedal
IDE00002,Transport mode
IDE00820,Activating and deactivating all development messages
IDE01550,Service position
IDE02152,Characteristics in production mode
IDE02269,MAS04382,Acknowledgement signals-Optical feedback during locking
IDE02332,Deactivate production mode
IDE02488,DWA Interior monitoring
IDE02711,ENG116690,Rear Window Wiper-Automatisches Heckwischen
IDE99999,Test-two hyphens
IDE99999,ENG123456,Test-four-Hyphens
IDE99999,ENG123456,Production mode,test-five-hyphens
```

Passing the above data through the following template has got me as close to what I need, but it still has a few issues:

```
$template = @'
{object*:{ide:IDE00001},{code?:ENG99061},{mode?:Production mode},{description?:Access control}}
{object*:{ide:IDE00001},{code?:ENG115730},{mode?:Dev mode},{description?:Aussenbeleuchtung}}
{object*:{ide:IDE00001},{code?:ENG115731},{mode?:Production mode},{description?:Virtuel_pedal}}
{object*:{ide:IDE02711},{code?:ENG116690},{description?:Rear Window Wiper-Automatisches Heckwischen}}
{object*:{ide:IDE00820},{description?:{!mode?:{!code?:Activating and deactivating all development messages}}}}
{object*:{ide:IDE01550},{description?:{!mode?:{!code?:Service position}}}}
{object*:{ide:IDE02488},{description?:{!mode?:{!code?:DWA Interior monitoring}}}}
{object*:{ide:IDE00002},{mode?:Transport mode}}
'@

$testText | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template -OutVariable out | Out-Null
$out.object
```

### Results thus far:

The result looks like:

```
ide      code      mode            description                                            
---      ----      ----            -----------                                            
IDE00001 ENG99061  Production mode Access control                                         
IDE00001 ENG115730 Production mode Aussenbeleuchtung                                      
IDE00001 ENG112304 Production mode Heckwischer                                            
IDE00001 ENG98647  Production mode Interior lighting                                      
IDE00001 ENG115729 Production mode Scheinwerferreinigung                                  
IDE00001 ENG115731 Production mode Virtuel_pedal                                          
IDE00002           Transport mode  Transport mode                                         
IDE00820                           Activating and deactivating all development messages   
IDE01550                           Service position                                       
IDE02152           production mode Characteristics in production mode                     
IDE02269 MAS04382                  Acknowledgement signals-Optical feedback during locking
IDE02332           production mode Deactivate production mode                             
IDE02488                           DWA Interior monitoring                                
IDE02711 ENG116690                 Rear Window Wiper-Automatisches Heckwischen            
IDE99999                           Test-two hyphens                                       
IDE99999 ENG123456                 Test-four-Hyphens
```

### The areas of issue:

```
IDE00002           Transport mode  Transport mode

IDE02152           production mode Characteristics in production mode

IDE02332           production mode Deactivate production mode
```

1. `Transport mode` should not be in the `description` column.
2. `production mode` should not be in the `mode` column. It has somehow picked this up from the `description`.

I just can't work it out. Therefore, if anyone has any ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, if your input data is systematic enough, you can parse it using a regular expression:

```
$inputText = @"
IDE00001-ENG99061-Production mode-Access control
IDE00001-ENG115730-Production mode-Aussenbeleuchtung
IDE00001-ENG112304-Production mode-Heckwischer
IDE00001-ENG98647-Production mode-Interior lighting
IDE00001-ENG115729-Production mode-Scheinwerferreinigung
IDE00001-ENG115731-Production mode-Virtuel_pedal
IDE00002-Transport mode
IDE00820-Activating and deactivating all development messages
IDE01550-Service position
IDE02152-Characteristics in production mode
IDE02269-MAS04382-Acknowledgement signals-Optical feedback during locking
IDE02332-Deactivate production mode
IDE02488-DWA Interior monitoring
IDE02711-ENG116690-Rear Window Wiper-Automatisches Heckwischen
"@ -split "`n"

$pattern = '^((?<ide>[IDE0-9]+)-)((?<code>[A-Z0-9]+)-)?((?<mode>Production mode|Transport mode)-?)?(?<description>.*?)$'

foreach ($line in $inputText)
{
    $isMatch = $line -match $pattern
    if (-not $isMatch)
    {
        Write-Warning "Cannot parse expression: $line"
        continue
    }

    New-Object psobject -Property ([ordered]@{
        'Ide' = $Matches.ide
        'Code' = $Matches.code
        'Mode' = $Matches.mode
        'Description' = $Matches.description
    })
}
```

You said that your data is not structured in the same way. Maybe your regex needs to be far more complex than the one given above. Or you run your parsing several times with different regular expressions if you can identify all different structures that might occur.